# $elemMatch vs $and giving different output for the same query in Mongo shell. Why?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am writing a mongo [query](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb-exercises/mongodb-exercise-9.php) to find the restaurants that achieved a score which is more than 80 but less than 100.

The following are the queries I wrote to achieve this.

```
db.restaurants.find({grades: {$elemMatch: {"score": {$gt: 80, $lt: 100}}}})
db.restaurants.find({"grades.score": {$gt: 80, $lt: 100}})
db.restaurants.find({$and: [{"grades.score": {$gt: 80, $lt: 100}}]})
```

The first query returns 3 outputs but the bottom two return 4 outputs. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the results to make a better explanation:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ac3f61effed1f90d366ac"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "score" : [11, 131, 11, 25, 11, 13]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Murals On 54/Randolphs'S",
    "restaurant_id" : "40372466"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ac3f61effed1f90d3674d"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "score" : [5, 8, 12, 2, 9, 92, 41]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Gandhi",
    "restaurant_id" : "40381295"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ac3f61effed1f90d368b0"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "score" : [31, 98, 32, 21, 11]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Bella Napoli",
    "restaurant_id" : "40393488"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4ac3f61effed1f90d3711c"),
    "grades" : [
        {
            "score" : [89, 6, 13]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "West 79Th Street Boat Basin Cafe",
    "restaurant_id" : "40756344"
}
```

The restaurant_id and score elements that matches the conditions seperately:

`$gt: 80`: 40372466 (131), 40381295 (92), 40393488 (98), 40756344 (89)

`$lt: 100`: 40372466 (11, 11, 25, 11, 13), 40381295 (5, 8, 12, 2, 9, 92, 41), 40393488 (31, 98, 32, 21, 11), 40756344 (89, 6, 13)

The bottom two queries looks for the array as a whole so 4 records are in both $gt and $lt groups.

But the first query with `$elemMatch` looks for each element of the array and apply the `{$gt: 80, $lt: 100}` query on each element. The record with `"restaurant_id" : "40372466"` has no element matches the query. Neither of these (`[11, 131, 11, 25, 11, 13]`) are between 80 and 100.

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
>   with at least one element that matches all the specified query
>   criteria.

That's why `$elemMatch` operator should be used on arrays to match multiple conditions in queries.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of `$elemMatch` [from MongoDB official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#elemmatch-query):

> The **$elemMatch** operator matches documents that **contain an array field** with ***at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria***.

e.g: With only two records in the scores collection as below:

```
> db.scores.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "results" : [ 75, 88, 89 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ 82, 85, 88 ] }
>
```

The following query matches only those documents where the results array contains **at least one element that is both greater than or equal to 80 and is less than 85**.

```
db.scores.find(
   { results: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 80, $lt: 85 } } }
)
```

Consider the first records `[ 82, 85, 88 ]` of the `results` array:

1. 82 => true, since 82 lies between 80 and 85.
2. 85 => false, since `$lt` not the `$lte`.
3. 88 => false, since not less than 85.

So, *at least one value in the array* found and as per specified query criteria, this record will be selected.

Second records `[ 75, 88, 89 ]`, let's find out *at least one record* which satisfied the criteria `$gte: 80, $lt: 85`:

1. 75 => false, since not greater than 80.
2. 88 => false, since not less than 85.
3. 89 => false, since not less than 85.

So, None of the elements of `results` array satisfied the criteria so rejected.

Final output would be:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ 82, 85, 88 ] }
```

Let's insert new records `"results": [ 1, 2, 3 ]` with `_id:3` in the same collection, records become as below:

```
> db.scores.find()
{ "_id" : 2, "results" : [ 75, 88, 89 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ 82, 85, 88 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

Now run the `$and` query as below:

```
db.scores.find({$and: [{"results": {$gte: 80, $lt: 85 } }] } )
```

***What would be the output?***

Since records with `_id:2` satisfied both the condition **88** and **89** greater than *80* as well the **75** is less than *85*, so records with `_id:2` selected.

Now the second records with `_id:1` all the results value are greater than *80* and **82** is less than *85*, so it is also selected.

Now come to second records with `_id:3` none of the elements satisfied the conditions so rejected.

So the final output be:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "results" : [ 75, 88, 89 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ 82, 85, 88 ] }
```

Other things, let us insert one more records `results:[86,92,93]}` with `_id:4` and what would be the result of the same `$and` query? think of it, you will figure it out yourself.